# facebook ease effect w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-animate

Can anyone recommend how to go about creating the "ease down" effect facebook implements today when you AJAX-load updates in your news feed? (When it reads "`load x new news feed articles`")
if I use `prepend`, the new updates will be inserted all at once.

I'm looking for a way to ease/slide down the old updates smoothly in order to make room for the new, incoming updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you insert all of your elements, make sure they have `display: none` then use:

```
$("some jquery selector").show("slow")
```

See the [jquery documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show#speedcallback)

Answer (score 0):

How about the [slideDown()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown) and [slideUp()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown#speedcallback) methods?

Note that these can be used to "ease in" the new incoming updates, which will cause the old ones to ease downward.

Answer (score 0):

[show()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show) will make the object expand both downward and to the right.

[slideDown()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown) will make the object expand downwards only.

If you want to achieve any other effects, use [animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate).